# Is there a way to control the number of partitions when reading a text file in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am reading a text file using the following command in PySpark

```
rating_data_raw = sc.textFile("/<path_to_csv_file>.csv")
```

Is there a way to specify the number of partitions that RDD rating_data_raw should be split into? I want to specify a large number of partitions for greater concurrency.

Comment: Could you add the python tag? This way will add highlight to your code

Comment: You can state the minimal number of partitions when reading the file, see in the documentation here - http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As other user said you can set the minimal number of partitions that will be created, while reading the file, by setting it in the optional parameter `minPartitions` of [textFile](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.textFile).

```
rating_data_raw = sc.textFile("/<path_to_csv_file>.csv", minPartitions=128)
```

Another way to achieve this is by using [repartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD.repartition) or [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD.repartition), if you need to reduce the number of partition you may use `coalesce`, otherwise you can use `repartition`.

```
rating_data_raw = sc.textFile("/<path_to_csv_file>.csv").repartition(128)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to read a .csv file and then check partitions with df to RDD conversion. I leave an example structure below.

```
dataset = spark.read.csv("data.csv", header=True, inferSchema='True')
colsDrop = ("data_index", "_c17", "song_title", "artist")
df = dataset.drop(*colsDrop)
rdd = sc.parallelize(df.collect()).partitionBy(8)
```

Here **.partitionBy()** allows you to control the partition number of an RDD object. It is also possible to find out these numbers with the **.getNumPartition()** method.

The only thing to note is that giving the number of partitions more than the number of threads on the CPU will not give us speed gain.

For example, the amount of threads in my CPU is 8, you can see a sample time distribution below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I can't gain speed after 8 partitions.

Comment: Also, if you want to use RDD API over df or sql, the default partition number is 1.
`trainingData=df.rdd.map(lambda x:(Vectors.dense(x[0:-1]), x[-1]))`
`print("Partition: ",trainingData.getNumPartitions())`

**Response: Partition:  1**